# API endpoint how to return a string with new line

Tags: java, string, api, endpoint

In my custom GET endpoint, I would like to return a String but, to "beautify" it, I would like to insert new line for each different information. I've tried with `\n\r` this way

```
return "Name of process definition: "+ obj.getString("processDefinitionName") + "\r\n" + "Start time of instance: " + obj.getString("startTime")
        + "||" + "End time of the instance: " + obj.getString("endTime") + "||" + "Total duration time(ms): " + obj.getInt("durationInMillis");
```

but it only prints a white space and the text is written on the same line. Why is it not working?

Comment: Note that the correct order should probably be `"\r\n"` .

Comment: Hi thank you for the hint, anyway nothing has changed :\

Comment: Are you looking at the result in a browser?

Comment: @Naya Yes, in Chrome

Comment: Then you should use HTML to format your response:)

Comment: Right, sorry, so stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **HTML tags** to display new line on browser. You can use **`<br/>`** tag to add new line. Browser parses your response in HTML form.